# Memory error while creating empty dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I was trying to create an empty pandas dataframe of 189522 x 2502. It's not that huge, I know.
And getting Memory error.
I have 8gb ram and about 4gb free ram. 
My python version 3.7.4 [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)].
I had to restart my pc 4 times now. Please help.
Thank you very much.

```
columns = list(range(0, 2502))
index = np.array(range(0, 189522))
data = pd.DataFrame(index=index, columns=columns)
```

Comment: I was able to run your code, after that `data.memory_usage().sum()` gives `3794988528` bytes, i.e about `3.79 GB`....

Comment: Even though you call it 'empty', its full memory is allocated,  189522 x 2502x8 is almost 4 GB.  If you run this code on a clean session and get the memory error, repeated attempts won't make a difference.

Comment: @QuangHoang Thanks. btw I was able to run it finally after terminating so many processes in task manager. But how can I ensure that I won't have to run it again after I close the kernel? Cz I don't know if it's gonna work the next time I run the cell.

Comment: Is this a jupyter notebook?

Comment: @hpaulj yes it is!